# R linear model regression line fitting

Tags: r, linear-regression, pearson-correlation

I'm trying to fit a linear model.  If I do this in excel, I get a sloped line (rather than horizontal which I get from R) and an r squared value of 0.125.

Clearly the correlation is weak, but I'm not getting much at all out of R.  Can anyone explain why?
[image: Scatterplot in R with R's attempt to fit a line - basically a horizontal line]

The code follows this structure:  Z <- lm (x ~y, data = df)

Answer (score 0):

I did something stupid but may as well leave it up in case anyone else does it too - I swapped x and y - it should be y~x